# Rotating a 2d drawing so I can animate it the other way

Tags: grease-pencil, 2d

How do I draw a 2d animation in another direction without rotating the entire image? I want to select the head/face and rotate it in the opposite direction without making the camera rotate in the animation. Here is the image below...
[image]

Comment: If you're wanting to invert the head, so that it faces the other way, you won't want to rotate it, obviously, since that would make it upside down when it gets into the new position. Instead, you want to scale it to a value of -1 in the horizontal axis. This tweak can be done in either Object Mode or Edit Mode, but there will be reasons for doing it one way or the other, depending on the structure of your rig. Naturally, you will need to create the inbetweens that transition from one head facing to the other.

Answer (score 1):

In the Outliner select your grease pencil object. **Item>Transform>Y scale = -1** will flip the object holding the drawing.